# How to suppress Cut, Copy and Paste Operations in TextBox in WPF?

Tags: wpf, textbox, wpf-controls

I want to suppress Cut, Copy and Paste operations in Text Box.

I don't want user to do any of these operations through keyboard or from default context menu in the text box .

Please let me know how can I restrict these operations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily using the CommandManager.PreviewCanExecute routed event. In your XAML, you would put the following on your TextBox element. This will apply to CTL+V, etc as well as the context menu or any buttons that you may have mapped to those commands so it's very effective.

```
<TextBox CommandManager.PreviewCanExecute="HandleCanExecute" />
```

Then in your code-behind, add a HandleCanExecute method that disables the commands.

```
private void HandleCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) {

    if ( e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Cut ||
         e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Copy ||
         e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Paste ) {

        e.CanExecute = false;
        e.Handled = true;

    }

}
```