# how to disable cut, copy paste and right click across all WPF forms

Tags: wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

We are building a WPF kiosk application.
We need to disable CUT COPY PASTE and RIGHT-CLICKs

Please how can this be done?

This SO post does not give a centralized solution for all forms:

[How to suppress Cut, Copy and Paste Operations in TextBox in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051144/how-to-suppress-cut-copy-and-paste-operations-in-textbox-in-wpf)

Comment: Is it just those things that you want to disable or all of the ContextMenu Items? BTW in `WPF` there are NO forms, use `Windows` and `Controls`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `Style` in your `App.xaml` in which you define:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox"> 
<!-- OR -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{x:Null}"/>
</Style>
```

But this will only work for the Items that are NOT in a `DataTemplate`.
**UPDATE:**
`App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="TestApp.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

And here is the `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xml:lang="en-GB"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
    xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:TestApp.Converters"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="478.889" Width="903.889">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="txtBx" MinHeight="150" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoWordSelection="True" 
                 MaxLines="10" 
                 TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" 
                 SelectionChanged="txtBx_TextHighlighted"
                 ToolTip="{x:Null}"
                 Margin="10"/>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

If you Right Click on the `TextBox` you will not have any `ContextMenu` available to you.
**UPDATE 2:**
Continuing from our chat, the `TextBox` was referencing other styles which were overriding whatever we set in the `App.xaml`. As the external styles were loaded after the `App.xaml`.

Comment: So you have your `TextBoxes` in `DataTemplates` or is your app not in `WPF` and it is in `UWP`? @CharlesOkwuagwu

Comment: it is wpf, no i don't use DataTemplates

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu could you tell us what you use then? If you could put a sample code here of how you use those `TextBox`es then it would be easier for me to help you more.

Comment: i use them on a standard window object, within a Grid

Comment: OK I will put an example of how I used the Style in my app and you can tell me then if it's any different then yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145618/discussion-between-charles-okwuagwu-and-xamlmax).