# Wpf Pasting event adds text twice

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I am trying to handle paste event on a WPF TextBox. I want to replace new line chars with coma and blankspace.

I suspect that (because I am adding a paste handler and not setting it) the existing paste handler is also triggered by pasting?

Code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    System.Windows.DataObject.AddPastingHandler(txtSearch, OnPaste);
}

private void OnPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    var isText = e.SourceDataObject.GetDataPresent(System.Windows.DataFormats.UnicodeText, true);
    if (!isText) return;

    var text = e.SourceDataObject.GetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.UnicodeText) as string;
    string parsedText = text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ", ");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text))
    {
          txtSearch.Text = parsedText;
    }
    else
    {
          txtSearch.Text += parsedText;
    }
}
```

While debugging I can see that `txtSearch.Text` is set to the value I want, but on gui there is some extra. The extra text is the string before the first new line chars.

for example if I paste:

```
Aaa
Bbb
Ccc
```

The result is: `AaaAaa, Bbb, Ccc`

But I want it to be: `Aaa, Bbb, Ccc`

Comment: As I exit the method the `txtSearch.Text` is set correctly. The textBox is empty before paste

Comment: You probably need to disable Paste on the TextBox. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3051187/1136211

Comment: @Clemens But I want the user to be able to paste?

Comment: I guess the key point is to call `e.CancelCommand();`

Comment: @Clemens I don't see how this is a duplicate. It is an unrelated problem about a similar topic. All your activity on this question was not helpful and all you did was delete actual helpful answers only to add the answer as a comment. Anyway `e.CancelCommand();` worked. Cheers m8

Comment: How would I possibly be able to "delete actual helpful answers" except my own? Besides that, the linked question is about exactly the same thing you're asking, i.e. how to modify pasted text. And as I told you, `e.CancelCommand()` is the key point, as explained in the answer to the linked question.